# String value is null

Tags: android, android-intent, null

I have a `ListView` with each row containing a `TextView`.  On user click, I'm getting the value of the `TextView` and storing it in a String variable, and the user is navigated to another activity where he / she needs to input some data on said `TextView`.  In order to not lose the information state of the first activity, I had to use `startActivityForResult()` and later get the information from the second activity with the method `onActivityResult()`.

The problem is this: I need to compare a value with that of the TextView in question, however the String variable which supposedly contains the TextView's value is null.

Before starting up the second activity I toasted the String value and it returned the correct string, however not in the `onActivityResult()`, where it returns null.

Why is this happening? Isn't the Intent I used suppose to retain all information of the opened activity?

*ListView's onItemClick*

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemID)
        {


            clickedError = ((TextView)itemView).getText().toString();
            String errorIDQuery = "SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_ERROR + " WHERE error_description LIKE '" + clickedError + "';";

                Cursor getErrorID = db.rawQuery(errorIDQuery, null);
                getErrorID.moveToFirst();
                errorID = getErrorID.getInt(0);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Repair.this, Material.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("materialList", materialList);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), clickedError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

*onActivityResult*

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap <String, String> materialDetails = (HashMap <String, String>)data.getSerializableExtra("map");
        Set<?> set = materialDetails.entrySet();
        Iterator<?> i = set.iterator();

        ArrayList<String> materialNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> materialAmounts = new ArrayList<String>();

        do
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();

            materialNames.add(me.getKey().toString());
            materialAmounts.add(me.getValue().toString());
        }
        while (i.hasNext());

        for(Error e : errorList)
        {
            // ----- COMPARING THE VALUES -----
            // here clickedError is null
            if(e.description.equals(clickedError)) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < materialNames.size(); j++)
                {
                    MaterialClass mc = new MaterialClass();
                    mc.setName(materialNames.get(j));
                    mc.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(materialAmounts.get(j)));
                    e.materialList.add(mc);
                }
                if (e.materialList.size() != 0)
                    e.checked = true;
                else
                    e.checked = false;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your String value as static so that it will retain its value. or you can use shared preference to save value and use it later.

Comment: Thanks.  It wasn't static.  I didn't even check that.

Comment: While making the value static lets it retain its value between instances, it is bad practice. You would not be able to use more than one separate instance of this class without interference. The answer by @delblanco (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18227585/316424) looks more appropriate to me.

Answer (score 2):

My guess: the activity is destroyed and restarted while moving to the second activity. This is easy to confirm with log messages in the activity life cycle methods(onCreate/onRestart/etc).

The following link might be of use to persist data during activity switching: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Making it static has some architectural downsides. For example the clickedError holds its value until the app's process is killed. This could interfere with onActivityResult calls.Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639860/static-variables-in-android) and [this](http://www.offthehill.org/articles/2011/06/03/java-static-variables-are-wrong-almost-always/)

Answer (score 0):

> This is working if its not ask me

```
TextView textviewDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourtextviewid);
clickedError=textviewDate.getText().toString();
```